# Will this circuit work using BC 108 transistor

Tags: transistors

Hi guys i have circuit diagram from everyday practical electronics magzine
and i want to make it but there are two problem about the circuits one is 
the transistor BC 108 used in this circuit and the second thing is i am 
wondering will that work having it made so i want to know is there any
equivalent of BC 108 and and will this circuit work ?
[image]

Comment: Try a 2N3904. Or a 2N2222.

Comment: BC547, BC548, BC327, BC328 ... Question is: What have you lying around? Look for: General purpose low power NPN.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any transistor will work for this circuit. The most convenient choices are usually the 2N3904 and 2N2222 simply for availability. That said, you might have some trouble with TR1, because the biasing circuit design is somewhat sensitive to \$V_{BE}\$ and \$\beta\$ variation. Build the circuit, and if you have any trouble, try varying the values of R2, R3, and R4.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother very grateful to you for helping me

Comment: If the OP lives in an European country he may also find more available some other compatible types like BC547/BC548/BC549.